# How to activate vibrate on watchOS 4 in Swift 4

Tags: xcode, apple-watch

I would to activate vibrate on my iWatch in watchOS 4 and Swift 4 on xCode 9. I tried to WKInterfaceDevice.playHaptic, WKInterfaceDevice.current().play but not working.

What is the useful technique in this case?

Here is my simple example Swift code and the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are developing an iOS app, since you are writing your code in ViewController. Haptics are unavailable on iOS app. Add this code in InterfaceController and try running this code on watchOS app.

Also you have added this code in didReceiveMemoryWarning function which is rarely called, I would suggest that you put this code in an IBAction associated with a button so that watch will vibrate each time you press the button.

about the error being shown in that image, your syntax for calling play() is wrong.
the correct way to call this function is

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that WKExtension is not set to background or inactive

what about

```
func play(_ type: WKHapticType)
```

Comment: I edited my question and inserted my sample code. What do I do?

Comment: try this: 

    WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Click)

Comment: So, in this case in Swift 4 or 3.2 I have an error: "'playHaptic' is unavailable" and the currentDevice() is current() and finally .Click is .click